# How to make new version of Android Application?

Tags: android

Hi I am new in Android and I want to upload new version of my Application(1.1) older is 1.0 is Launched.
And after Launching this version I have made two Changes so my version code now goes to 3.
now I am trying to launch my version 1.1 using this code in Manifest But I can't do.
please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stress" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Manifest of my old version is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.stress" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.0">
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Try changing the versionName to 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to do this,

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Does it mean anything? I dont think so, You just need to do this android:versionName="1.1"

Answer (score 1):

You changed the xml version code instead of the android versionName

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stress" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.1">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.stress" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.1">
       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

you have to update both version code and version name

initial was 1 for 1.0

so make version code 2 and version name 1.1

Answer (score 0):

you should have to update both version name and version code,make it 1.1 from 1.0 in ur manifest file
code is below
package name would be yours

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.pkg" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.1">
```